# Creating a tree at run time

Tags: java, tree, nodes

everyone.

I am trying to come up with a way to allow the user to create a tree at run-time, with a branching factor of 2 and an unlimited depth (depends on user).

The user must begin with the **root_node**, then go on to the root node's two children (**left_node** and **right_node**). after that the left child becomes the root and the user does the same process and moves on to the right child.

Any help on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from doing that? What part do you have problems with?

Comment: You can start from [hire](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/)

Answer (score 0):

**Are you looking for something like this?**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
  import java.util.Queue;

public class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    public void add(int value) {
        root = addRecursive(root, value);
    }

    private Node addRecursive(Node current, int value) {

        if (current == null) {
            return new Node(value);
        }

        if (value < current.value) {
            current.left = addRecursive(current.left, value);
        } else if (value > current.value) {
            current.right = addRecursive(current.right, value);
        }

        return current;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return getSizeRecursive(root);
    }

    private int getSizeRecursive(Node current) {
        return current == null ? 0 : getSizeRecursive(current.left) + 1 + getSizeRecursive(current.right);
    }

    public boolean containsNode(int value) {
        return containsNodeRecursive(root, value);
    }

    private boolean containsNodeRecursive(Node current, int value) {
        if (current == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (value == current.value) {
            return true;
        }

        return value < current.value
          ? containsNodeRecursive(current.left, value)
          : containsNodeRecursive(current.right, value);
    }

    public void delete(int value) {
        root = deleteRecursive(root, value);
    }

    private Node deleteRecursive(Node current, int value) {
        if (current == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (value == current.value) {
            // Case 1: no children
            if (current.left == null && current.right == null) {
                return null;
            }

            // Case 2: only 1 child
            if (current.right == null) {
                return current.left;
            }

            if (current.left == null) {
                return current.right;
            }

            // Case 3: 2 children
            int smallestValue = findSmallestValue(current.right);
            current.value = smallestValue;
            current.right = deleteRecursive(current.right, smallestValue);
            return current;
        }
        if (value < current.value) {
            current.left = deleteRecursive(current.left, value);
            return current;
        }

        current.right = deleteRecursive(current.right, value);
        return current;
    }

    private int findSmallestValue(Node root) {
        return root.left == null ? root.value : findSmallestValue(root.left);
    }

    public void traverseInOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            traverseInOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(" " + node.value);
            traverseInOrder(node.right);
        }
    }

    public void traversePreOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(" " + node.value);
            traversePreOrder(node.left);
            traversePreOrder(node.right);
        }
    }

    public void traversePostOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            traversePostOrder(node.left);
            traversePostOrder(node.right);
            System.out.print(" " + node.value);
        }
    }

    public void traverseLevelOrder() {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        Queue<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<>();
        nodes.add(root);

        while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {

            Node node = nodes.remove();

            System.out.print(" " + node.value);

            if (node.left != null) {
                nodes.add(node.left);
            }

            if (node.left != null) {
                nodes.add(node.right);
            }
        }
    }

    class Node {
        int value;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            right = null;
            left = null;
        }
    }
}
```